# NGINX : no live upstreams while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx, udp, nginx-config, filebeat

I am running multiple filebeats on a server listening on various ports . I have set of udp packets incoming on a server on port 2055 . These packets are routed to upstream filebeat server in round robbin manner . When I directly listen on a single filebeat on port 2055 , filebeat can process around 20k/second without nginx . However I route these packets through nginx the above below error is encountered

`udp client: 10.224.3.178, server: 0.0.0.0:2055, upstream: "stream_backend", bytes from/to client:192/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0`

Following is my Nginx stream Block Configuration
`

```
stream {
   log_format proxy '$remote_addr [$time_local] '
                '$protocol $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received '
                '$session_time "$upstream_addr" '
                '"$upstream_bytes_sent" "$upstream_bytes_received" "$upstream_connect_time"';
   access_log /var/log/nginx/stream.log proxy;

   upstream stream_backend {
        # least_conn;
        # upstream_connect_time 10 ;
        # random two least_time=connect;
        zone backend 100k;
        server 127.0.0.1:2056;  
        server 127.0.0.1:2057;
        server 127.0.0.1:2058;
        server 127.0.0.1:2059;
        server 127.0.0.1:2060;
        server 127.0.0.1:2061;
        server 127.0.0.1:2062;
        server 127.0.0.1:2063;
        server 127.0.0.1:2064;
        server 127.0.0.1:2065;
       
   }
    
   server {
       listen 2055 udp;
        proxy_pass stream_backend;
        proxy_bind $remote_addr transparent;
        proxy_buffer_size 10000k;
        # upstream_connect_time 10 ;
        proxy_timeout 10s;
        # proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
        proxy_responses 1;
        # health_check udp;
   }

}
```

`

Nginx has a bunch of timeout directives. I don't know if I'm missing something important. Any help would be highly appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

I guess proxypass is not taken correctly by Nginx.

`proxy_pass` should be under `location`.

Try add under

```
location ~ {}
```